# confirmation not appearing after submission

Tags: jquery, html

Got a jsfiddle here where I am trying to sort out a confirmation which should appear after a submit to make sure if user wants to submit:

http://jsfiddle.net/baxGm/1/

Problem is that confirmation is not appearing, does anyone know why this is?

**HTML:**

```
<form id='choiceForm' action='assessment.php' method='post'>
    <p><strong>Chosen Assessment:</strong></p>
    <table>
    <tr>
        <th></th>
        <td><input type='hidden' id='currentId' name='Idcurrent' readonly='readonly' value='' /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>Assessment:</th>
        <td><input type='text' id='currentAssessment' name='Assessmentcurrent' readonly='readonly' value='' /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>Date:</th>
        <td><input type='text' id='currentDate' name='Datecurrent' readonly='readonly' value='' /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>Start Time:</th>
        <td><input type='text' id='currentTime' name='Timecurrent' readonly='readonly' value=''/></td>
    </tr>
    </table>
    <p id='submitchoicebtn'>
        <input id='choiceSubmit' type='submit' value='Choose Assessment' name='choiceSubmit' onClick='myClickHandler(); return false;'/>
    </p>
    <div id='currentAlert'></div>
</form>
```

**Jquery:**

```
function choicevalidation() {
    var isDataValid = true;
    var currentAssesO = document.getElementById("currentAssessment");
    var currentAssesMsgO = document.getElementById("currentAlert");

    currentAssesMsgO.innerHTML = "";

    if (currentAssesO.value == "") {
        $('#targetdiv').hide();
        currentAssesMsgO.innerHTML = "Please Select an Assessment to edit from the Assessment Drop Down Menu";
        isDataValid = false; 
    } else {
        currentAssesMsgO.innerHTML = "";
    }
    return isDataValid;
}

function showConfirm() {
    var examInput = document.getElementById('curentAssessment').value;
    var dateInput = document.getElementById('currentDate').value;
    var timeInput = document.getElementById('currentTime').value;

    return confirm("Are you sure you want to take the following Assessment:" + "\n" + "Exam: " + examInput +  "\n" + "Date: " + dateInput + "\n" + "Time: " + timeInput);
}  

function myClickHandler() {
    if (choicevalidation()) {
        showConfirm();
    }
}
```

**UPDATE:**

```
        <body>

    <script type="text/javascript">


        $('#sessionsDrop').change( function(){

            $('#targetdiv').hide();

            if( $(this).val() !== '' ){
                var text = $(this).find('option:selected').text();
                var split = text.split(' - ');
                $('#currentId').val($(this).find('option:selected').val());
                $('#currentAssessment').val( split[0] );     
                $('#currentDate').val( split[1] );     
                $('#currentTime').val( split[2] );     
            }
            else{
                $('#currentAssessment,#currentDate,#currentTime,#currentId').val('');           
            }
        });

        $('#assessmentForm').delegate('change','select',(function(warnings)
{
    return function()
    {
        warnings.html('');
    };
}($('#warnings'))));



function validation(e) {

                var isDataValid = true;

                var moduleTextO = document.getElementById("modulesDrop");

                var errModuleMsgO = document.getElementById("moduleAlert");

         if (moduleTextO.value == ""){
          $('#targetdiv').hide();
          $('#assessmentForm').hide();
          $('#choiceForm').hide();
          $('#submitchoicebtn').hide();
          errModuleMsgO.innerHTML = "Please Select a Module";
          isDataValid = false;    
        }else{
                errModuleMsgO.innerHTML = ""; 
            }

                if (isDataValid === false)
    {
        if (e.preventDefault)
        {
            e.preventDefault();
            e.stopPropagation();//VERY important
        }
        e.returnValue = false;
        e.cancelBubble = true;
    }

            return isDataValid;

            }

       function choicevalidation() {

                var isDataValid = true;

                var currentAssesO = document.getElementById("currentAssessment");

                var currentAssesMsgO = document.getElementById("currentAlert");

          currentAssesMsgO.innerHTML = "";


      if (currentAssesO.value == ""){
          $('#targetdiv').hide();
          currentAssesMsgO.innerHTML = "Please Select an Assessment to edit from the Assessment Drop Down Menu";
          isDataValid = false; 
        }else{
            currentAssesMsgO.innerHTML = "";
        }
            return isDataValid;


        }


        function showConfirm(){

              var examInput = $('#currentAssessment').val();
            var dateInput = $('#currentDate').val();
            var timeInput = $('#currentTime').val();

            return confirm("Are you sure you want to take the following Assessment:" + "\n" + "Exam: " + examInput +  "\n" + "Date: " + dateInput + "\n" + "Time: " + timeInput)          
} 


$('#choiceSubmit').click(function(e){myClickHandler(e)});

function myClickHandler(e){
    e.preventDefault(); 
     if(choicevalidation()){ 
                if(showConfirm())
                   $('#choiceForm').submit();
     } 
}

    </script>   

   Logged In: <b>Mayur Patel</b> | <a href='./studentlogout.php'>Logout</a>     
        <div class="topcorner"><a id="studentmenulink" href="studentmenu.php">Back to Menu</a></div>

        <noscript style='color: red'><img src="Images/warning-2.fw.png" alt="Javascript Warning" id="warningImage" name="warningSymbol"/> In order to use this application without any problems, you must have javascript enabled</noscript>


        <div id="js">


<h1>TAKE AN ASSESSMENT</h1>   

<form action="/u0867587/Mobile_app/assessmentchoice.php" method="post" onsubmit="return validation(event);">
<table>
<tr>
<th>Module: <select name="modules" id="modulesDrop">
<option value="">Please Select</option>
<option value="CHI2513_Systems Strategy_1">CHI2513 - Systems Strategy</option>
<option value="CHT2220_Interactive Systems_4">CHT2220 - Interactive Systems</option>
</select></th>
</tr>
</table>
<p><input id="moduleSubmit" type="submit" value="Submit Module" name="moduleSubmit" /></p>
<div id="moduleAlert"></div>
<div id="targetdiv"></div>
</form>

<div id='lt-container'>
<form action='/u0867587/Mobile_app/assessmentchoice.php' method='post' id='assessmentForm'>
<p id='warnings'></p>
<p><strong>Selected Module:</strong> CHI2513 - Systems Strategy <input type='hidden' value='1'></p>
<p><strong>Assessments:</strong> <select name="session" id="sessionsDrop">
<option value="">Please Select</option>
<option value='28'>LDREW - 09-01-2013 - 09:00</option>
<option value='29'>BQNYF - 10-01-2013 - 10:00</option>
<option value='22'>WDFRK - 17-01-2013 - 09:00</option>
<option value='26'>POKUB1 - 25-01-2013 - 15:00</option>
</select> </p>   
</form>
</div>
<div id='rt-container'>
<form id='choiceForm' action='assessment.php' method='post'>

    <p><strong>Chosen Assessment:</strong></p>
    <table>
    <tr>
    <th></th>
    <td><input type='hidden' id='currentId' name='Idcurrent' readonly='readonly' value='' /> </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <th>Assessment:</th>
    <td><input type='text' id='currentAssessment' name='Assessmentcurrent' readonly='readonly' value='' /> </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <th>Date:</th>
    <td><input type='text' id='currentDate' name='Datecurrent' readonly='readonly' value='' /> </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <th>Start Time:</th>
    <td><input type='text' id='currentTime' name='Timecurrent' readonly='readonly' value=''/> </td>
    </tr>
    </table>
    <p id='submitchoicebtn'>
    <input id='choiceSubmit' type='submit' value='Choose Assessment' name='choiceSubmit'/>    
    </p>
    <div id='currentAlert'></div>
    </form>

    </div>

</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
document.getElementById('js').style.display = 'block';
</script>

    </body>
```

Comment: To add on to what antejan said you will get a `cannot get property of undefined` error because there is no dropdown atm. If you give it some input you can see that it does confirm http://jsfiddle.net/aTgAz/

Comment: @BeardFist There is a drop down menu, I tried to limit the code so I might of made a mistake. Do you know what i will do, I will get the html from the view source and post that

Comment: code updated to show html from view source

Comment: so something like: http://jsfiddle.net/aTgAz/3/ is what you are aiming for?

Comment: @BeardFist It doesnt work in my app when I have tried your fiddle. Nothing happens when I click on Submit button for assessment in application.

Comment: see my comment below, I just didn't add the actual `submit()` because it just 404's in fiddle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

myClickHandler() is not a global function it is in context of jquery onload function, so you get "myClickHandler is not defined" error.

Use regular jquery event binding instead of inline onclick and function

```
$("#choiceSubmit").click(function(){
  if(choicevalidation()){ 
    showConfirm(); 
  } 
  return false;
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/baxGm/3/

Comment: It works in the fiddle as you showed but when I put it in my full code it does not work. It still submits with no confirmation. Is this because my ful code contains multple forms? I included an update in my question showing full code. What happens is user submits a module drop down menu, then underneath it displays assessment drop down menu, when user submits this, I want confirmation to appear, if they cancel obviously they stay on the same page. If they click on Ok then they should navigate to next page

Comment: hard to say without working code. do you have any bugs in console?

Comment: I tried to limit the code so I might of made a mistake. Do you know what i will do, I will get the html from the view source and post that

Comment: Try to wrap your scripts inside `$(function(){ ... });` - you can use source of html generated by jsfiddle as reference. I created a fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/rnmYZ/, is it working correct?

Comment: Do you want me to wrap each indivdual script to its own `$(function(){ ... });` or wrap the whole javascript in one `$(function(){ ... });`?

Comment: Whole js. This is meaning "run everything inside when html and other scripts loaded and ready to use".

Comment: I updated the fiddle to  jsfiddle.net/rnmYZ/2 but no luck when wrapping it in function

Comment: I believe the problem you are having is that it is submitting before it fires the `onclick` event, you could use a `preventDefault()` or just make it a normal button and submit on confirm like I did here http://jsfiddle.net/aTgAz/6/ (the submit is commented out just for debugging purposes)

Comment: I tried this fiddle as well and still doesn't work, button does nothing, can you put in answer the changes you made, You changed the button and some functions but still not working, button still not submitting and there are no errors

Comment: Look at what is happening at app here [here](http://helios.hud.ac.uk/u0867587/Mobile_app/Text16.php)

Answer (score 0):

Alright, in this case the `input` is of type `submit` which means its default behavior is to submit. In this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/efuZA/ I have not changed the type but instead added `e.preventDefault()` to keep it from submitting right away then used `submit()`.

Comment: I tried your code from fiddle, didn't work, paste my code into your fiddle but it also works in fiddle only. I posted whole code in update. Can't believe why this is taking so long. Here is app you can use to see what is happening [here](http://helios.hud.ac.uk/u0867587/Mobile_app/Text16.php)

Comment: what is this line `document.getElementById('js').style.display = 'block';` for? It is throwing a `Cannot read property 'style' of null` error because there is nothing with the id `js`

Comment: I will remove that line of code, I tried to copy and paste the code from the main app into the page and removed some code to limit it down. But it is not needed in this situation